# undefined method `original_filename' for nil:NilClass in active_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload

although I saw this problem in other blogs, I couldn't make it works in my case.
My view:

```
<%= semantic_form_for :routes_status_race, :url => status_race_admin_routes_path do |f| %>
    <% contact_array = Contact.all.map {|contact| [contact.name, contact.id]}%>
    <% route_importer_array = RouteImporter.all.map {|importer| [importer.name, importer.id]}%>
    <%= f.inputs do%>
        <%= f.input :contact, :as => :select, :collection => Contact.all %>
        <%= f.input :route_import, :as => :select, :collection => RouteImporter.all %>
        <%= f.input :uploaded_data, :action => :status_race, :multipart => true, :as => :file %>
    <%end%>
    <input name='commit' type='submit' method='post' value='Import'/>
<%end%>
```

My controller:

```
collection_action :status_race, :method => :post do

    uploaded_io = params[:uploaded_data].original_filename

    File.open(Rails.root.join('app/importers', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'w') do |file|
      file.write(uploaded_io.read)
    end

    RoutesQuickcom.new.run(uploaded_io.original_filename)
    render "status_race"
  end
```

I get this error:undefined method `original_filename' for nil:NilClass in my controller and I don't know how to fix it, any help will be appreciate, thanks!

Comment: try change this `params[:uploaded_data]` to `params[:routes_status_race][:uploaded_data]`

Comment: I changed it, but now I have this error: undefined method `original_filename' for "Quickcom-Standard-20121107-FULL.csv":String.    Quickcom-Standard-20121107-FULL.csv is the name of the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You called `original_filename` 3 times, remove two `original_filename` and it will works:

```
collection_action :status_race, :method => :post do

  uploaded_io = params[:uploaded_data].original_filename

  File.open(Rails.root.join('app/importers', 'uploads', uploaded_io), 'w') do |file|
    file.write(uploaded_io.read)
  end

  RoutesQuickcom.new.run(uploaded_io)
  render "status_race"
end
```